# How to add leading blank rows to a CSV?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv, write.table

I'm doing some pre-processing where after importing a csv with `read.csv`, I drop two columns from the csv and I need to export back the processed data in a new csv.
The original csv has 2 blank rows at the start of the file, which I would need to add back to the new csv.

I read the csv, as follows, by skipping the first three rows (incl. the headers):

```
Bla <- read.csv("Bla.csv", skip = 3, header = TRUE)
```

After taking care of the processing steps, I write a csv as follows:

```
write.csv(Bla, file = "Clean_Bla.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I would like that the first three rows of the new csv were left blank, as in the original cvs. I tried with `cat`, but that doesn't seem to work. I guess this is because what `cat` does is appending the blank row at the end of the csv.

```
cat("\n", file='Clean_Bla.csv', append=TRUE)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a working example, you have to put NA for missing value into the dataframe before, then you have to say to R to write "" for NA

```
  #data your dataframe before writing
    data<-data.frame(Type=c("A","B","D","D","E","E"),
                 Ratio=c(5,6,3,3,4,4),
                 Number=c(65,74,43,34,23,12))
a<-rep(NA,dim(data)[2])
a<-rbind(a,a,a)
write.table(a, file = "Clean_Bla.csv", row.names = FALSE,na="",col.names=FALSE,sep=",")
write.table(data, file = "Clean_Bla.csv", row.names = FALSE,na="",append=TRUE,sep=",")
```

Comment: sorry, now is OK

Comment: It worked perfectly. It's a neat solution. Thanks Federico!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to read the 2 lines separately and attach it to your `Clean_Bla` after you are done. This way, you don't have to actually specify what the first 2 rows are. You just take it straight from the original dataset:

```
Bla_first3 = read.csv("Bla.csv", nrow = 2, header = TRUE)
Bla = read.csv("Bla.csv", skip = 3, header = TRUE)

# After cleaning
CleanBla = rbind(Bla_first3, Bla)

write.csv(CleanBla, file = "Clean_Bla.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Note that this assumes your original dataset has the same columns as your final dataset